# How can I print this equation properly?

Tags: equations, formatting, matrices

I am trying to print the following equation in an article

```
H = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
1 & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \cdots & q_{1p+1} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \cdots & q_{2p+1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
q_{p+11} & q_{p+12} & \cdots & q_{p+1p+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{n1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}

=

\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{t}q_{1} & x_{1}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{1}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
x_{2}^{t}q_{1} & x_{2}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{2}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{n}^{t}q_{1} & x_{n}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{n}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{n1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

I am putting the code like you can see and to between `\equation` and `$$`, but the equation is split into a line by matrix, how can solve it and put the equation properly in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
H = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
1 & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \cdots & q_{1p+1} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \cdots & q_{2p+1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
q_{p+11} & q_{p+12} & \cdots & q_{p+1p+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{n1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}
%
= \\
%
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{t}q_{1} & x_{1}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{1}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
x_{2}^{t}q_{1} & x_{2}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{2}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{n}^{t}q_{1} & x_{n}^{t}q_{2} & \cdots & x_{n}^{t}q_{p+1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \cdots & x_{n1} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \cdots & x_{np} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can i delete the number of the equation?

Comment: Use `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` instead, @Tlaloc-ES, if you don't want numbers. Using `$$` in LaTeX is wrong.

Comment: Thanks and is there any way of center the equation?

Comment: Yes, @Tlaloc-ES. You need to use the `gathered` environment in that case. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES: How about [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/deQ5DF0n)?

Comment: You can simply use `the `gather*` environment.

Answer (score 9):

Some comments about your code:

- First and foremost, get rid of all blank lines in the math environments.
- I don't think that it is correct, typographically speaking, to use `\cdots` as *the* typographic ellipsis in all places in the matrices. In rows 1, 2, and 4, it should be `\dots` (or `\ldots`). In row 3, three of the four `\cdots` instructions really ought to be `\vdots`; the 3rd out of four, though, should be `\ddots`.
- The subscript notation in the `Q` matrix in row 1 is not well designed. E.g., instead of `1p+1` and `p+12`, do write `1,p+1` and `p+1,2`, etc.
- The transpose notation you employ in the first matrix in the second row is not well chosen. I suggest you place the transpose symbol -- whether `^t`, `^{\prime}`, `^{\top}`, or whatever strikes your fancy -- between the two vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page dimensions appropriately
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'pmatrix' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
H 
&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & \dots & x_{1p} \\
1 & x_{21} & \dots & x_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_{n1} & \dots & x_{np}
\end{pmatrix}%_{\!\!\!n\times(p+1)}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \dots & q_{1,p+1} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \dots & q_{2,p+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{p+1,1} & q_{p+1,2} & \dots & q_{p+1,p+1}
\end{pmatrix}%_{\!\!\!(p+1)\times(p+1)}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \dots & x_{n1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \dots & x_{np}
\end{pmatrix}%_{\!\!\!(p+1)\times n}
\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}{}'q_{1} & x_{1}{}'q_{2} & \dots & x_{1}{}'q_{p+1} \\
x_{2}{}'q_{1} & x_{2}{}'q_{2} & \dots & x_{2}{}'q_{p+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{n}{}'q_{1} & x_{n}{}'q_{2} & \dots & x_{n}{}'q_{p+1}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
x_{11} & x_{21} & \dots & x_{n1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{1p} & x_{2p} & \dots & x_{np}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This positive vote was necessary :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - In fact, your upvote raised my year-to-date rep count to over 40K! :-)

Comment: I like to vote for everyone :-) especially for the elegance of the answer. What do we have left of this life at the end?